# Leakage of field lines in solenoid

Tags: inductance

Considering a long solenoid, the field intensity at its centre is given by $\mu_0NI$, where you know what the symbols mean. Now if we move towards one end of it, the field intensity becomes $\frac{\mu_0NI}{2}$. This clearly suggests that the field lines leak from within the solenoid (as they can't be destroyed abruptly).

This was my speculation. Please correct me if I am wrong, and explain it in detail.

Comment: In general we take the length of the solenoid to be much larger than the radius of the solenoid so that leakage of field is minimized. At that point, the uniform magnetic field characteristic of the solenoid is not true; but in the limit that I mentioned it really dosent matter. Look up Griffiths.

Answer (score 0):

> This clearly suggests that the field lines leak from within the
>   solenoid (as they can't be destroyed abruptly).

Taken from [Cylindrical Magnets and Ideal Solenoids](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.3880)

[image]